# Vectorized initial values - Simulation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, matlab, simulation

I want to simulate a certain stochastic process, lets say a geometric brownian motion (in matlab) with various initial values. Let's say, $$S_{0} = [0.01:0.01:1].$$ For every value of $S_{0}$, I want to store a path. Even though I can simulate a path for a specific $S_{0}$, I don't know how to efficiently vectorize initial values. Any ideas?

My idea:

a = [0.01:0.01:1];

for i=1:size(a)

```
S0(i) = a(i); 
path(i) = GBMPATH(S0(i), T, r, sigma, mu);
```

end

However, I doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store the paths in a matrix where each column contains a path.

**Edit**: I think that I spotted your mistake which lies in the syntax for the for-loop. If you use MATLAB, which I think you do by the syntax, size(a) = [1,10]. And thus if you want to run i = 1:size(a), it will only take the first argument of size(a) which equals 1. A fix would be to use size(a,2) or length(a).

Comment: thanks for the responce. Please, see my edit. I want for every initial value to run the same function.

Comment: That should work though. I think that I spotted your mistake which lies in the syntax for the for-loop. If you use MATLAB, which I think you do by the syntax, size(a) = [1,10]. And thus if you want to run i = 1:size(a), it will only take the first argument of size(a) which equals 1. A fix would be to use size(a,2) or length(a).

Comment: Thank you very much ! I apologize for wasting your time with such a simple matter. The answer was so obvious.

Comment: No problem, I just like to help people once in a while :)

Comment: please, add your comment-solution to the answer so as I can vote as useful.